# How to test Database.query

Tags: apex

We have our managed package and we need to install in another org. And there are many custom fields which already exist there. So we cannot create the custom field in our org because it will cause the duplicate issue. So how should i write the test method to cover the dynamic query custom fields?

I am using dynamic query to query records like

```
List<Account> accList = Database.query('select Name,customfield__C  
                                       from Account');
```

as customfield__C  is not present in my org it's value getting retrieved dynamically , so how to give customfield__C  value in my test class.

Comment: dynamically means Is that field a Formula Field?

Comment: for tests you should create your test data first. There you can fill in that `customfield__c` and then query it

Comment: customfield__c  is a text field which is not present in my org.

Comment: If not present in your org., then you have to create it first and then query it...
Otherwise, it will show you an error at the time of execution of Query itself.

Comment: Yes, i cannot create because there are around 100 fields.

Comment: I am afraid that you can not create custom field during test class. I think you should rewrite your test class

Comment: It is our managed package and we have to install in another org. And there the custom field already exist. That's why we cannot create the field in our org because it will cause the duplicate issue. So how should i write the test method so that it covers the dynamic query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query fields that are not existent in your org. First you'd have to create it either manually or using the api. Anyway in your test class you also need to create the records you want to test the query on. 
So you'd have something like:

```
List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();

for(Integer i=0 ;i<200;i++){
Account a = new Account(Name='test'+i, customfield__c='abcd');
acclist.add(a);
}

insert acclist;
List<Account> accList = Database.query('select Name,customfield__C  
                                       from Account');
System.debug(accList);
```

Comment: It has to be said that this is not a test as it is not asserting the value you're reading. Tests are there to test business behaviour. I would add a line asserting that you've read the custom field correctly. Having said that, all you're testing is Salesforce DML.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test querying of a custom field, you should add the custom field in the org where you're doing the tests. I'm afraid I don't know of any other way to test it.

You mention that your org already has "around 100 fields". This makes me think that you're using one single org to test many different projects/products/customisations.

What I would suggest is to keep different orgs for different projects. This will keep your code and metadata clean and isolated (ie: your time tracking app will be on a different org than your charitable donation app, just to mention an example). This is what we do in my company. Developer orgs are free, after all :)

If you do that, then adding fields to test your Apex code is trivial.